# Twilio Conference for certain Caller-IDs

Tags: twilio

We currently use Twilio Conference, however we would like to allow certain participants based on their caller-IDs, rest to be rejected. Currently anyone who dials the number for conference can participate and this is not something we want due to privacy, security and compliance.

How can we do it with TwiML?

Best,

Savas

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with TwiML Bins (static TwiML) but you can use a Twilio Function for this or even Twilio Studio with the split based on Widget, to determine if the trigger.message.From number is allowed.

Below is an example Twilio Function you can modify for your purpose. Currently, it only allows certain CallerID in as moderators and provides these numbers the ability to start a conference, others can only be participants in an active conference. You can see the steps to set-up a Twilio Function [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/wireless/tutorials/communications-guides/implement-voicemail#create-voicemail-action-in-functions) (just apply similar steps to setting up the code below). You can extend the function and return a Twilio TwiML [Reject verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/reject) in the participant path for non-moderators.

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
    let callerId = event.From || null;
    let conferenceParams = {};
    let conferenceName = "My Conference Room";
    let moderators = ["+1813279xxxx", "+1813393xxxx", "+1813918xxxx"];
    conferenceParams.beep = true;
    if (moderators.indexOf(callerId) === -1) {
      conferenceParams.startConferenceOnEnter = false;
      conferenceParams.endConferenceOnExit = false;
    }
    else
    { 
      conferenceParams.startConferenceOnEnter = true;
      conferenceParams.endConferenceOnExit = true;    
    }
    twiml.dial().conference(conferenceParams, conferenceName);
    callback(null, twiml);
};
```

Comment: Thanks Alan, I tried and it works well. However, non-moderators, which can be any number, can still dial-in and join an ongoing conference. Is there a way which only moderators can join and start a conference?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the approach you are looking for, both Functions are viable.

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {

    let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
    let callerId = event.From || null;
    let conferenceParams = {};
    let conferenceName = "My Conference Room";
    let moderators = ["+1678785xxxx", "+1813393xxxx", "+1813918xxxx"];
    conferenceParams.beep = true;
    if (moderators.indexOf(callerId) === -1) {
      twiml.reject({reason: 'busy'});
      callback(null, twiml);
    }
    else
    { 
      conferenceParams.startConferenceOnEnter = true;
      conferenceParams.endConferenceOnExit = true;
      twiml.dial().conference(conferenceParams, conferenceName);
      callback(null, twiml);
    }
};
```